# Audio AVAssetWriter mute

Tags: ios, audio, avassetwriter

I'm trying to record audio with AVAssetWriter, and I'm getting weird skips in the output file.

I've crossed checked the code with another app that does work - anybody witness this inconistant behavior?

10x!

Answer (score 0):

I've witnessed this before and it was driving me mad!!

Check if you are performing heavy processing some place else in the code - AT THE SAME TIME. Turned out for me bringing the cpu to a 100% for a long time caused it to leap.